# Disable Forefront Endpoint Protection 2010 Desktop Alerts

Tags: microsoft-forefront-2010

Is it possible to disable desktop alerts for FEP 2010, without disabling realtime protection?

I.e., the notification that pops up that says:

[image]

We want to maintain realtime protection, neutralise threats in the background, but not bother our users with these alerts.

Comment: Which method are you using to configure your FEP clients? SCCM, Group Policy, script, other?

Comment: @jscott we are using SCCM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to a quick google search, this doesn't appear to be possiable.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/FCSNext/thread/ef0ef5ea-b5a6-4793-864c-b6b557e46330

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask what search term you used? I spent a good hour looking this up before I posted this question.

Comment: Sure, third result from the top https://www.google.com/search?q=disable+forefront+endpoint+protection+notifacations&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&ie=&oe=#hl=en&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-Address&sa=X&ei=QD9GT6L7HeL00gGOvZyODg&ved=0CCgQvwUoAQ&q=disable+forefront+endpoint+protection+notifications&spell=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.,cf.osb&fp=92affcf7fd72e753&biw=1680&bih=910